# Theorem of perturbation of the identity

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having troubles with the last statement of this question:

> Let $\phi:A\to \mathbb R$ be a contraction defined in an open set
>   $A\subset \mathbb R$. Prove the map $f:A\to \mathbb R$, defined by
>   $f(x)=x+\phi (x)$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ to an open set $f(A)\subset \mathbb R$. Besides that, if $A=\mathbb R$, then $f(A)=\mathbb R$.

I need help with $f(A)=\mathbb R$. How can I prove that?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

Following the solution above, I'm trying to prove $f(x)-f(0)\geq (1-q)x$ for $x\gt 0$, where q is the contraction constant, if I prove this, the solution will come easily.

I need help in this part.

Thanks again

Comment: With "for any $x\in\mathbb R$" you probably mean "for all $x\in\mathbb R$", don't you? I think "any" is a bit ambiguous here.

Comment: @ElmarZander thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $\phi$ is a contraction on $\mathbb R$ you know that $f(x)-f(0)\geq (1-q)x$ for $x>0$, where $q$ is the contraction constant, and something similar for $x<0$. This should enable you to show that for arbitrarily large $M$ there is an $x^+$ such that $f(x^+)\geq M$, and $x^-$ such that $f(x^-)\leq -M$. Now use the fact that $\phi$ and thus also $f$ is an homeomorphism (i.e. continuity) to see that $[-M,M]\subset f(\mathbb R)$.

EDIT: to show the inequalities:
for $x\geq0$ we have $f(x)-f(0) = x + \phi(x) - \phi(0) \geq x - |\phi(x) - \phi(0)| \geq x - q|x| = (1-q)x$
for $x\leq0$ we have $f(x)-f(0) = x + \phi(x) - \phi(0) \leq x + |\phi(x) - \phi(0)| \leq x + q|x| = (1-q)x$, .

Comment: you removed the norm, is it correct? thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, which is easy to do, since if you know that $|a|\leq b$ with $b\geq0$, then you know that $-b\leq a\leq b$, and the inequality follows by plugging in the definition of $f$ and the contraction inequality.

Comment: Are you sure that $f(x)-f(0)\geq (1-q)x$? I think the correct sense of the inequality is $f(x)-f(0)\leq (1-q)x$

Comment: Please, see my edit on this.